# Why when using webclient to download a file it's not downloading and getting to the completed event after a millisecond?

Tags: c#, winforms

First I tried both :

DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler and AsyncCompletedEventHandler bit it didn't work.
Then I tried both :

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
```

This time it's getting right away to the completed event it's not downloading and not updating the progressBar1.

```
private void Download()
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin"), desktop);
        }

        private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Download Completed";
        }

        private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
            progressBar1.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100;
        }

        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
            progressBar1.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100;
        }

        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Download();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the `button1_Click` and `Download` methods are `async` and add `await` before `client.DownloadFileAsync`.

Or you can use the synchronous version `client.DownloadFile`

Comment: `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` isn't a `Task` so you can't `await` it. You can `await` a `WebClient.DownloadFile` manually putted into `Task.Run`.