# How can I calculate and display download speed using webclient?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal is to calculate and display on label4.Text the download speed while downloading.

```
private void Download()
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => label1.Text = "Download file completed.";
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => label2.Text = FormatBytes(e.BytesReceived);
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => label4.Text = e.
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    label3.Text = "%" + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
                    label3.Left = Math.Min(
                        (int)(progressBar1.Left + e.ProgressPercentage / 100f * progressBar1.Width),
                        progressBar1.Width - label3.Width
                    );                   
                };

                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin"), @"d:\10GB.bin");
            }
        }
```

At the line with the label4.Text I want to display the speed.

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => label4.Text = e.
```

Comment: Can you please accept this answer, if it has answered your question correctly https://stackoverflow.com/a/69517951/6527049

Comment: You can e.g. start a `Stopwatch` just before the download begins, then compute the speed as a function of "bytes downloaded / stopwatch seconds elapsed" in the progress function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As *@AKX* suggested, `Stopwatch` class help you to calculate bytes per second receive while downloading file.

Create a **field** in class scope (example based on WPF Application):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    private readonly System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
}
```

When initializing `WebClient` (as simplest way), create 2 handlers: for `WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged` event and for `WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted` event. Then before you call `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync()` call `stopwatch.Start()` to begin measuring time.

```
using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += OnDownloadProgressChange;
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadFileComplete;

    stopwatch.Start(); // Start the Stopwatch
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(downloadLink, fileName); // Run file download asynchroniously
}
```

In `DownloadProgressChanged` event handler you can combine `DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs`'s `BytesReceived` property and `Stopwatch`'s `Elapsed.TotalSeconds` property to get download speed:

```
private void OnDownloadProgressChange(object sender, System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Calculate progress values
    string downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} MB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
}
```

I divide `BytesReceived` twice by 1024 to get value in MB instead of Bytes, but you can choose as you wish. Also I format result value to `0.00` (to get "1.23 MB/s" for example).
You can also calculate and format other `DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs` properties for you purposes if needed.

And finally, at `WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted` event handler you should reset the `Stopwatch` to stop it and reset its measured time for other new downloads:

```
private void OnDownloadFileComplete(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Reset();
}
```

Complete version may look like this (`MainWindow.cs`):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private readonly System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    private void BtnDownloadFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri downloadLink = new Uri("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin");
        string fileName = "H:\\100MB.bin";

        btnDownloadFile.IsEnabled = false; // Disable to prevent multiple runs

        using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += OnDownloadProgressChange;
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadFileComplete;

            stopwatch.Start();
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(downloadLink, fileName);
        }
    }

    private void OnDownloadProgressChange(object sender, System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Calculate progress values
        string downloadProgress = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
        string downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} MB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
        string downloadedMBs = Math.Round(e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
        string totalMBs = Math.Round(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";

        // Format progress string
        string progress = $"{downloadedMBs}/{totalMBs} ({downloadProgress}) @ {downloadSpeed}"; // 10 MB / 100 MB (10%) @ 1.23 MB/s

        // Set values to contols
        lblProgress.Content = progress;
        progBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void OnDownloadFileComplete(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblProgress.Content = "Download complete!";
        stopwatch.Reset();
        btnDownloadFile.IsEnabled = true; // Restore arailability of download button
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Label x:Name="lblProgress" 
               Content="Here would be progress text" 
               Margin="10,0,10,5" 
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progBar" 
                     Height="20" 
                     Margin="10,0,10,5" />
        <Button x:Name="btnDownloadFile" 
                Content="Download file" 
                Width="175" 
                Height="32" 
                Click="BtnDownloadFile_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

How it would look:

[image]

Comment: How do you know to position the controls one under each other in the center like that ? I always have to drag them and move them for an hour until they get close to how they are in your screenshot.

Comment: I set it through `Margin` property of each element. `Margin="10,150,10,0"` for Label, `Margin="10,180,10,0"` for ProgressBar and `Margin="0,205,0,0` for Button. 150 / 180 / 205 - is margin value from top of window. It look centered when window is in Normal state. If I maximize it - controls will still be at 150 / 180 / 205 pixels from top and would not be centered and would look like sticked to top of window. You can also use `StackPanel` with `Vertical` orientation to align controls that way, and then only try to center StackPanel.

Comment: I've edited XAML example in answer and added `StackPanel`. Now StackPanel and its items will be centered at any window size and state (except `Minimized`, of course).